# how to combine several RDD with different lengths into a single RDD with a specific order pattern?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have several RDD with different lengths:

```
RDD1 : [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
RDD2 : [1, 3 ,2, 44, 5]
RDD3 : [D, F, G]
```

I want to combine them into one RDD, with the order pattern:

> every 5 rows: takes 2 rows from RDD1 , takes 2 from RDD2 ,then takes 1 from
>   RDD3

This pattern should loop until all RDD exhausted.
the output above should be:

```
RDDCombine : [a,b,1,3,D,  c,d,2,44,F,  e,f,5,G, g]
```

How to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

*Background: I'am designing a recommender system. Now I have several RDD outputs from different algorithms, I want to combine them in some order pattern to make a hybrid recommend.*

Answer (score 0):

I would not say it's an optimal solution but may help you to get started.. again this is not at all production ready code. Also, the number of partitions I have used is 1 based on fewer data, but you can edit it.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("local[*]")
    conf.setAppName("some")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,3,2,44,5),1)
    val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),1)
    val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Seq('D','F','G'),1)

    val groupingCount = 2

    val rdd = rdd1.zipPartitions(rdd2,rdd3)((a,b,c) => {
      val ag = a.grouped(groupingCount)
      val bg = b.grouped(groupingCount)
      val cg = c.grouped(1)
      ag.zip(bg).zip(cg).map(x=> x._1._1 ++ x._1._2 ++x._2
      )
    })


    rdd.foreach(println)
    sc.stop()


  }
```